# Posting scores with test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using test users to post game scores to Facebook using `FB.API` and `Facebook.HttpMethod.POST`. When I am doing this by using access token, everything works perfectly fine.

Then I building and uploading the Unity binary, which is accessible online. I tried to login to Facebook with one of test users by using `Login as this test user`, and tried to play in a regular way. However, I noticed that when I am doing that way, scores are not being saved. Is that suppose to be like that?

I am doing this for `publish_actions` to get approved, but if test users work only in development mode, how I can find about my scores being saved also by playing online?

Comment: Why don't you take your app live then?

Comment: Sleepy Panda, what exactly do you mean? It is live, but when I am playing live version (i.e. with test users), scores are not being saved.